# Subversion client 1.9 offline installation on RHEL

Tags: linux, svn, svn-client

My OS version:
uname -or
**2.6.32-642.3.1.el6.x86_64 GNU/Linux**

I want to install subversion client to Redhat Linux offline, How can I achieve that ?

I've downloaded the below list of rpm files from http://opensource.wandisco.com/rhel/6Workstation/svn-1.9/RPMS/x86_64/

---

mod_dav_svn-1.9.0-rc3.x86_64.rpm
mod_dav_svn-1.9.4-3.x86_64.rpm
serf-1.3.7-1.x86_64.rpm
serf-devel-1.3.7-1.x86_64.rpm
subversion-1.9.4-3.x86_64.rpm
subversion-debuginfo-1.9.4-3.x86_64.rpm
subversion-devel-1.9.4-3.x86_64.rpm
subversion-gnome-1.9.4-3.x86_64.rpm
subversion-javahl-1.9.4-3.x86_64.rpm
subversion-perl-1.9.4-3.x86_64.rpm
subversion-python-1.9.4-1.x86_64.rpm
subversion-tools-1.9.4-3.x86_64.rpm

---

And when I try **yum install subversion-1.9.4-3.x86_64.rpm** i get below error:

> Error: Package: subversion-1.9.4-3.x86_64 (/subversion-1.9.4-3.x86_64)
>              Requires: libserf-1.so.1()(64bit)

Or if I try "**rpm -ivh *.rpm**" I get below error

> Error
>   Failed dependencies:
>           httpd >= 2.2.3 is needed by mod_dav_svn-1.9.0-rc3.x86_64
>           subversion = 1.9.0-rc3 is needed by mod_dav_svn-1.9.0-rc3.x86_64
>           httpd >= 2.2.3 is needed by mod_dav_svn-1.9.4-3.x86_64
>           pkgconfig(libcrypto) is needed by serf-devel-1.3.7-1.x86_64
>           pkgconfig(libssl) is needed by serf-devel-1.3.7-1.x86_64
>           libgnome-keyring.so.0()(64bit) is needed by subversion-gnome-1.9.4-3.x86_64

But, I don't know what to do, to full install package for subversion client only. Anything else that I need to offline installation ? For complete use of that subversion client..

Comment: I was able to install Collabnet Subversion client without any error, but not the Wandisco .